# React Native: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement

Tags: android, macos, osx-yosemite, react-native

I have installed react native on Mac OS 10.10.5 (14F1713) Yosemite. When I start the AwesomeProject - its all ok - I see app "Welcome to React Native". When I try to start any app from github (like this https://github.com/VctrySam/AirBnb) I have got the red screen with error "Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement."

I use Android Studio 2.3. On XCode React don`t work.
My configuration:
node-7.8.0.yosemite
watchman 4.7.0
react-native-cli 2.0.1
package.json from AwesomeProject:
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "0.42.3"

Could someone help me please?

Comment: have you tried downgrading node to 6.*? you can use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) for that

Comment: The VctrySam/AirBnb project is using a really old version of React Native.  How you trying to start that app?  There have been a number of breaking changes between version 29 (the one used by the project) and version 42 (the one you say you're using).

Comment: Thank you, I`ll try. Should I uninstall node 7 before?

Comment: through "brew uninstall"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with "react": "^15.3.2" and "react-native": "^0.35.0". Following workaround worked for me. Turning on **Debug JS Remotely** enabled me to run the app without the error.